# Send automatically email to different-2 event orgainzer for their particular event in php?

Tags: php, mysql, email, mysqli, cron

I  have following table for events

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
|event_ID| org_name | eventName |     org_email   | status |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| 101    | santosh  |  10Km     | santo@gmail.com | Active |
| 102    | sandeep  |   5Km     | sande@gmail.com | Active |
| 103    | Sahil    |   3Km     | sahil@gmail.com |  Past  |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

second table where I am storing participate details

```
-------------------------------------------
|event_ID| p_name   | p_age | booking_date |
-------------------------------------------
| 101    | Vikram   |  26   |  17-04-2017  |
| 101    | vikrant  |  23   |  17-04-2017  |
| 102    | vikas    |  22   |  17-04-2017  |
| 103    | sanjeev  |  22   |  17-04-2017  |
--------------------------------------------
```

So, now I want to sent emails to event organizer on daily basis their booking ticket status, I am using following file for cron job org_cron.php

```
<?php
$query = SELECT COUNT(event_ID) AS ticketCount WHERE event_id = 101 AND status LIKE 'active';
$sql = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
if($rows>0){
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
  $dayTickets = $row['ticketCount'];
 }
 mail();
}
?>
```

Here, I have to put manually event_id in query but I want dynamically so that my other event id catch and sent their email also when cron job run.

Comment: you have to write two query for that.in first query get all the event_id to which you want to send mail and after that using foreach loop you can able to send mail each one of them

Comment: @Jenish Please suggest how do i write two query.

Comment: missing from table and use join with group by event_ID

Comment: @JYoThI just wondering that what is need of group by event_ID, i need each event_ID and run my query according each event_ID.

Comment: "select event_id  from table_name" thats all

Comment: try this single query select count(e.event_ID),e.org_email from events as e  join join participate as p on e.event_ID=p.event_ID where e.status="active" group by e.event_ID

Comment: @JYoThI OK let me try this.

Comment: @JYoThI, i have tried but it show all participant data, but i wanna to send email to organizer their tickets details not all.

Comment: @Jenish, How can i use foreach loop, i have gotten my all event_id.

Comment: you got event id as array right? so now you have to do is: "foreach($datas as $data){  print_r($data);  }" you get first event_id in print data.

Comment: @Jenish yes i am getting event id as array like " Array ( [event_id] => 101) Array ( [event_id] => 102 )" these are my active events, so my next step to count ticket count from other table respectively found event_id. so how can i use in this query (SELECT COUNT(event_id) as count WHERE  event_ID = ' ')

Comment: now you have to use foreach loop like::: foreach ($datas as $data){ print_r($data['event_id']);} you get single event id in foreach loop now in each loop you just have to run your query

Comment: @Jenish i am doing like this $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT event_id FROM events WHERE status LIKE 'active'");
foreach($query as $data){
 $e_id = $data['event_id'];
 $newQuery = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(event_id) FROM 
 members where event_id = '$e_id'");
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($newQuery)){
  $ticketCount = $row[COUNT(event_id)]; 
}
}
but this code is not working.

Comment: yeah thats right, now just use query for cron  job